# How to get handle to a cell field in Extjs Grid

Tags: extjs

The data for the grid looks something like this:

```
data: [{
    field1: abc
    field2: [
        {value: 0, label: Blue}, 
        {value: 1, label: Green}
    ]
},
{
    field1: def
    field2: [
        {value: 0, label: Red}, 
        {value: 1, label: Pink}
    ]
}]
```

---

grid component config looks something like:

```
{
xtype: 'grid',
....
    columns: [
        {
            dataIndex: field1
        },
        {
            dataIndex: field2
            editor: {
                xtype: combobox,
                displayField: label,
                valueField: value,
                store: new someSampleStore();
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Now, the grid's column #2 has a combobox.
For Grid's row 0, column 1; combobox dropdown should display these options: Blue, Green
For Grid's row 1, column 1; combobox dropdown should display these options: Red, Pink

Do I need to manually load the data into each combobox (each row) or is there any way I can specify config in column definition so that the combobox picks up data for 'field2' ?

Comment: I'd have a look at the documentation first http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0/5.0.1-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.grid.plugin.RowEditing-event-beforeedit
make an attempt to do *something* and then come back and ask a question specifically.

Comment: Sorry , i realize the question wasn't clear enough. I have edited the question.
I did try beforecellclick event on the grid so that i can get the field and set the data for the combobox. but i could not get handle to the combobox field.

Comment: From the information provided I'm guessing that you may be better off with a [PropertyGrid](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0.1/#!/api/Ext.grid.property.Grid). Define some common combo boxes and their stores that can be used throughout your application such as Colour Combo and use those. Generally an editor column with combo would be used when all rows use the same values in the combo so that you only define it once and they all share it, like a Order Status Combo or something similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the code below.  In essence it does what you want but only works after the first click.  I'll let you figure that out. ;-)

Demo: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/gec

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'Fiddle',

    launch: function() {


        var comboStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
            fields: ['value', 'label'],
            data: [{
                name: '',
                value: ''
            }],
            proxy: {
                type: 'memory',
                reader: {
                    type: 'json',
                    rootProperty: 'items'
                }
            }
        });

        Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
            storeId: 'employeeStore',
            fields: ['firstname', 'lastname', 'seniority', 'dep', 'hired'],
            data: [{
                firstname: "Michael",
                lastname: "Scott",
                seniority: 7,
                dep: "Management",
                hired: "01/10/2004",
                comboData: [{
                    label: 'Test1',
                    value: 'testval1'
                }, {
                    label: 'Test2',
                    value: 'testval2'
                }, {
                    label: 'Test3',
                    value: 'testval3'
                }]
            }, {
                firstname: "Dwight",
                lastname: "Schrute",
                seniority: 2,
                dep: "Sales",
                hired: "04/01/2004",
                comboData: [{
                    label: 'Dwight1',
                    value: 'testval1'
                }, {
                    label: 'Dwight2',
                    value: 'testval2'
                }, {
                    label: 'Dwight3',
                    value: 'testval3'
                }]
            }, {
                firstname: "Jim",
                lastname: "Halpert",
                seniority: 3,
                dep: "Sales",
                hired: "02/22/2006",
                comboData: [{
                    label: 'Jim1',
                    value: 'testval1'
                }, {
                    label: 'Jim2',
                    value: 'testval2'
                }, {
                    label: 'Jim3',
                    value: 'testval3'
                }]
            }, {
                firstname: "Kevin",
                lastname: "Malone",
                seniority: 4,
                dep: "Accounting",
                hired: "06/10/2007",
                comboData: [{
                    label: 'Kevin1',
                    value: 'testval1'
                }, {
                    label: 'Kevin2',
                    value: 'testval2'
                }, {
                    label: 'Kevin3',
                    value: 'testval3'
                }]
            }]
        });

        Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
            title: 'Column Demo',
            store: Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('employeeStore'),
            columns: [{
                text: 'First Name',
                dataIndex: 'firstname',
                editor: {
                    xtype: 'combobox',
                    displayField: 'label',
                    valueField: 'value',
                    store: comboStore,
                    fields: ['value', 'label']
                }
            }, {
                text: 'Last Name',
                dataIndex: 'lastname'
            }, {
                text: 'Hired Month',
                dataIndex: 'hired',
                xtype: 'datecolumn',
                format: 'M'
            }, {
                text: 'Department (Yrs)',
                xtype: 'templatecolumn',
                tpl: '{dep} ({seniority})'
            }],
            selType: 'cellmodel',
            plugins: {
                ptype: 'cellediting',
                clicksToEdit: 1,
                listeners: {
                    beforeedit: function(editor, context, eOpts) {
                        testData = context.record.data.comboData;
                        comboStore.setData(testData);
                    }
                }
            },
            width: 400,
            forceFit: true,
            renderTo: Ext.getBody()
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Rob.. It worked for me..
About the "it only works after first click", I set queryMode: 'local' to fix it.

Comment: @optimusPrime glad it worked out and that you were able to fix the issue on first click ;)

Comment: But, would it be possible to have combobox in each row have its own instance of store and load the data for each when the grid loads first time ?
something like this - 
<code>
columns: [
...
 {
 header: dropdown,
 dataIndex: column2
 editor: {
   xtype: 'combobox',
   displayField: 'label',
   valueField: 'value',
   store: new Ext.data.Store({
    fields:[],
    data: []
   }),
   fields: ['value', 'label']
  }
 }  
]
</code>

and in grid afterrender event - 

<code>
{
 get combobox at grid(row[i], column[1]); // iterate
 {
   combobox.store.load(data);
 }
}
</code>

Comment: Yes I guess you could do that if you can get a reference to the individual combo easily enough but this would be pretty expensive in terms of resources when you can just re-use a single store?